# MSTeams deep link issue

Tags: office365, microsoft-teams

I have created a company directory app with different deep links.
Most of them work, but I am encountering issues with some.
Data source is Office 365 users

**CALL BY E-MAIL ADDRESS**

- Does not work on iPhone / mobile device!
- On iPhone the Teams app opens, but it does not do anything.
- On Windows it works on some employees, but not on all! I thought it might have something to do with capital letters in mail or available status. But I have tried different things, and I can't seem to call some users no matter how the e-mail is spelt or what status they have.
- Any suggestions on how to make it work on iPhone and what might cause the issue with calling some users?

**msteams:/l/call/0/0?users=" & ThisItem.Mail**

**CALL BY TELEPHONE NUMBER (with Teams)**

- Works on iPhone.
- Teams for Windows adds an extra country code to the number, and it doesent ring.
- +47 XXXX becomes +47 47 XXXXX
- Temporary fix: Made PowerApps substitute + with 00.
- Any suggestions on how to make Windows Teams see the +47? Or is my temporary fix the permanent one?

**msteams:/l/call/0/0?users=4:" & Substitute(varPhone, "+", "00"**

**CHAT**

- Works both on Windows computer and iPhone.

**msteams:/l/chat/0/0?users=" & ThisItem.Mail**

Comment: We were able to repro the CALL BY E-MAIL ADDRESS issue. We are looking into the the CALL BY TELEPHONE NUMBER (with Teams) issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response!
The second issues regarding "call by e-mail address": That it doesn't work for calling all users. It works for users with only lower case letters in mail/user principal name. If they have uppercase letters it does not work. Any knowledge on this?

Comment: There is already a bug raised for deeplinks not working with uppercase letters.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Is there some way for me to track the status of this bug?

Comment: No, these are internal and you would not have access to them.